# password_verify always returns true

Tags: php, authentication

I'm working on a login page and stumbled across this problem where no matter what password i write, i'm able to log in.

I checked the values of $password, $row['password'], $pwdCheck and all had the values they needed to be.

The hashed password gets saved in a varchar(255).
I more than double checked the names and everything i thought of but if you think about something please let me know.
As far as i know the problem lies in password_verify.

I know this isn't the best practice of making a login page but for now it works.

Thanks

````
<?php

if ( isset($_POST['login-submit']) ) {
    require '../../files/includes/functions.php';
    $mysqli = get_db();
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    // check if the email is in the database
    $sql ='SELECT * FROM taxisvl_diritems WHERE email =?';
    $stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($mysqli);
    if ( empty($email) || empty($password) ) {
        header("Location: /inloggen?error=emptyfields");
        exit();
    }
    else {
        // check to see if we can run the query
        if ( !mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt,$sql) ) {
            header("Location: /inloggen?error=sqlerror");
            exit();
        }
        else {
            // bind the value to the parameter in the query statement
            mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 's', $email);
            // run the query
            mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
            $result = mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt);
            // check if we have a result for the given email
            if ( $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result) ) {
                // check the password
                $pwdCheck = password_verify($password, $row['password']);
                if ( $pwdCheck = true) {
                    // user is logged in
                    // create sessions to retreive users info
                    $_SESSION['id'] = $row['id'];
                    $_SESSION['email'] = $row['email'];
                    $_SESSION['name'] = $row['name'];
                    header("Location: /dashboard"); 
                    exit();
                }
                else {
                    header("Location: /inloggen?error=wrngpassword");
                    exit();
                }
            }
            else {
                header("Location: /inloggen?error=wrngemail");
                exit();
            }
        }
    }
} else {
    echo 'Login not set';
}
?>```
````

Comment: `if ( $pwdCheck = true)` < that will *always* be true, since you're assigning instead of comparing; consult the duplicate.

Comment: Oh wow what a mistake. Thanks a lot!

Comment: A good tip to avoid this kind of thing would be to run code quality tools against your code. Tools like PHPMD, PHPCodeSniffer, and friends would pick up errors like this instantly.